# iOS: how to read the installed configuration profile from app?

Tags: ios, profile

The configuration profile is installed by the weblink, and just want get some information from the configuration profile in the ios application.

But don't know how & where to get the profile.

Checked a long time for this issue, but I couldn't find a solution.